# Laravel 5.4 route for input post

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I'm new to laravel and I am stuck in place where I need to put information in to DB.

I guess I have done something wrong in form action and routes.

my route file

```
    ---------------------Admin menu creation routes -----------------------------
*/

    Route::resource('menu', 'MenuController');
```

here is my create menu blade

```
  @extends('admin.main')

@section('content') 
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form action = "{{ url('/menu')}}" method = "POST">

            <fieldset>

                <input type="text" id="menuName" name="menuName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu name">
                <input type="text" id="linkName" name="menuLink" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu link ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

controller

```
      public function store(Request $request) {
          $this->validate($request, [
              'menuName' => 'required',
              'menuLink' => 'required'
          ]);
          return 123;
      }
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this in your controller after validating the request:
(this will create the entity and store it in db)

```
Menu::create([...]);
```

or this will do the same :

```
$menu = new Menu([...]);
$menu->save();
```

don't forget to replace the dots by the key=>value attributes of your model. eg:

```
Menu::create([
'attribute' => 'value'
]);
```

as the store method is empty, you must implement it yourself.